# Mastermind (HTML+jQuery+PHP) - Problem with repeated numbers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, algorithm

I'm trying to make an Html + Javascript + PHP version of Mastermind game. The PHP simply generates a random 3-digit code, in a range from 0 to 9.

```
<?php
function randomCode() {
    $Code = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0,9);
        $Code[] = $n;
    }
    return implode($Code); //turn the array into a string
}
$codice= randomCode();
echo(json_encode($codice));
?>
```

I made a program with jQuery that tells me if the code is right or not. If it is not, it suggests a black circle for each correct number in the right place, and a white circle for each right number but in the wrong place.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var code="";
$("#codice").val("");
function Turno(){
    var tentativo = $('#codice').val();
    $("#codice").val("");
    if( tentativo.length == 3){
        if( tentativo == code){
            $("#esito").html("codice giusto");
        }else{
            $("#esito").html("codice errato");
        }
        var rnrp="";
        var rnwp="";
        var NumeriRipetuti=[];
        for (var i=0; i<tentativo.length; i++){
            /*Se nel codice c'è la cifra i del tentativo*/
            /*If in code there is i number of my guess*/
            var posC = code.indexOf(tentativo[i]);
            if(posC != -1){
                var posizionedellaripetizione = code.indexOf(tentativo[i], posC+1);
                /*controllo che la cifra nel codice sia eventualmente ripetuta*/
                /*check if that number is in the code more than once*/
                if(posizionedellaripetizione != -1){
                    /*se non l'ho già messo tra i numeri ripetuti*/
                    /*if i did't put the number in "Repeated Numbers" before*/
                    if(NumeriRipetuti.indexOf(tentativo[i])==-1){
                        if(tentativo[i]==code[i]){
                            /*aumento il numero di cifre giuste posizionate correttamente*/
                            /*number of right number in right place+1*/
                            rnrp+="\u25CF";
                        }else{
                            /*altrimenti aumento il numero di cifre giuste ma posizionate male*/
                            /*number of right number in wrong place+1*/
                            rnwp+="\u25CB";
                        }
                        while(posizionedellaripetizione != -1){
                            /*controllo se la ripetizione è in posizione giusta (+pallino nero) altrimenti (+pallino bianco)*/
                            /*check if the number repeated is in the correct position*/
                            if(tentativo[posizionedellaripetizione]==code[posizionedellaripetizione]){
                                rnrp+="\u25CF";
                            }else{
                                rnwp+="\u25CB";
                            }
                            posizionedellaripetizione= code.indexOf(tentativo[i], posizionedellaripetizione+1);
                        }
                        /*lo metto nei numeri ripetuti*/
                        /*i put the number in the "Repeated Numbers"*/
                        NumeriRipetuti.push(tentativo[i]);
                    }
                }else{
                    /*se la posizione è la stessa*/
                    if(tentativo[i]==code[i]){
                        /*aumento il numero di cifre giuste posizionate correttamente*/
                        rnrp+="\u25CF";
                    }else{
                        /*altrimenti aumento il numero di cifre giuste ma posizionate male*/
                        rnwp+="\u25CB";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var para = document.createElement("LI");                  // Create a <p> element
        var t = document.createTextNode(tentativo+" "+rnrp+rnwp);
        para.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("sequenze").appendChild(para);
    }else{
        $("#esito").html("il codice deve essere di 3 cifre");
    }
}
function Arrenditi(){
     alert("Peccato! La soluzione era "+code);
}
$.getJSON("MasterMind.php", function (result) {
    code=result;
    console.log(code);
    $('#conferma').click(
        function(){
            Turno();
        }
    );
    $('#arrenditi').click(
        function(){
            Arrenditi();
        }
    );
    $("#codice").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            Turno();
        }
    });
});
```

It works perfectly if the code does not contain repetitions (for example 123) and if I do not try to write a number with repetitions (for example, if the code is 123 and I write 333). I tried to solve the problem with an array of numbers already encountered during the "for" loop, but it does not seem to work. How can I handle these repetitions in the code and attempts?
This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MasterMind.css" />-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="MasterMind.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1 id="title">MasterMind</h1>
            <h2 id="subtitle">Cerca di indovinare la combinazione di 3 numeri</h2>
            <form name="game">
                <label>Il codice segreto è:</label>
                <input id="codice" type="text">
                <input id="conferma" type="button" value="Conferma">
                <input id="arrenditi" type="button" value="Arrenditi">
            </form>
            <div id="result">
                <h3 id="esito"></h3>
                <h4>Tentativi:</h4>
                <ol id="sequenze">
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking to solve this and I started the same way you did: Taking every number from "tentativo" and compare it to the numbers from "code". It got complicated. And then I realised: Why not to the other way around? :) Take the mountain to Mohamed :) And the problem got 100 times easier. Imagine that there are 2 groups of 3 peoples with numbers from 0 to 9 on there t-shirts, siting in front of each other. Group 1 is "tentativo" and group 2 is "code". Now imagine that every person in group "code" has one and only one object, a piece of paper, that they try to give to a person from group "tentativo". He first draws on that paper: a white circle or a black circle.  If the person in front of him  has the same number on the t-shirt, he writes a black circle and he gives him the piece of paper (same number same place) with no question asked (if the receiving person already had a piece of paper he throws it away). Now if the person in front of him has a different number he writes a white circle on his piece of paper and looks to the other persons to find one with the same number on the t-shirt. If he finds one he first ask if that person has a piece of paper. If the answer is Yes he looks to the next person and so on until he finds a person that answers NO and gives that person the piece of paper with that white circle on it or he is just left with it. And this is the algorithm. Now all is left is to ask the persons from the "tentativo" group" to open the pieces of paper and that is the answer :)

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
             $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#check").click(function(){
               code = $("#code").val();
               tentativo = $("#tentativo").val();
               tentativo_papers = [];
               for (i=0; i<code.length; i++) {
                   paper = "";//nothing written yet
                   if  (code[i] == tentativo[i]) {
                       //draws a back circle and asks the person in front
                       paper ="*";
                       tentativo_papers[i] = paper; 
                       //this is a black circle so if this tentativo person
                       // had a white cricle it is thrown away
                   }
                   else {
                       paper = "o"; //draw a white circle and look for all other pers from tentativo
                       for (j=0; j < tentativo.length;  j++) {
                           if (i==j) continue; //except the person in front of him
                           if (code[i] == tentativo[j]) {
                               //now the question
                               if (tentativo_papers[j] == null) {
                                   tentativo_papers[j] = paper;
                                   break; //he gaved his piece of paper/no need to continue
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
               $("#result").val(tentativo_papers);
               });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       code <input type="number" id="code"  size="3">
       tentativo <input type="number" id="tentativo"  size="3">
       <input type="button" id ="check" value="check">
       result<input type="text" id="result">
    </body>
</html>
```